# How to implement implicit extern c - LLVM

Tags: llvm, extern, llvm-ir

I am trying to build a way to use extern C++ functions in my LLVM code - for example:

```
extern "C" DLLEXPORT double printd(double X) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%f\n", X);
  return 0;
}
```

I would like to be able to call `printd` in my LLVM IR code.

I know that I have to implement a JIT to get this working, but I am not exactly sure what elements of a JIT enable calling functions from C++ code or how to link that code to my IR code.

---

#### Edit

IR Code (`out.ll`)

```
declare double @printd(double)

define double @__anon_expr() {
entry:
  %calltmp = call double @printd(double 1.000000e+01)
  ret double %calltmp
}
define i32 @main() {
call double @__anon_expr()
ret i32 0
}
```

I generate the above code using C++:

```
IR->print(llvm::errs());
```

Finally I run it using:

```
$ lli out.ll
```

And I get this error:

```
LLVM ERROR: Program used external function '_printd' which could not be resolved!
```

---

#### Edit 2

When I run `clang out.ll -lmylib -o a.out`

```
warning: overriding the module target triple with x86_64-apple-macosx10.12.0 [-Woverride-module]
1 warning generated.
ld: library not found for -lmylib
clang-6.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

#### Edit 3

```
$ clang out

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_printd", referenced from:
      ___anon_expr in out
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-6.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

```
$ lli out

lli: out:1:1: error: expected top-level entity
���� �� �__text__TEXT ��__literal8__TEXT@__compact_unwind__LD(@H�__eh_frame__TEXThX�
                                                                                    h$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ functions that are declared as `extern "C"` can be called just like regular C functions (that's what `extern "C"` does), so all you need to is a declaration and then a regular call instruction. So that'd be:

```
; At the top-level:
declare double @printd(double)

; Somewhere inside the definition of a function that calls printd:
%42 = call double @printd(double %23)
```

Then all you need is to link against your library when creating the final executable.

> I know that I have to implement a JIT to get this working

Calling external functions works perfectly well in AOT-compiled code. You don't need to JIT-compile in order to call external functions.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. What is the best way to link my IR code to my C++ code?

Comment: @pudility What's your current process to generate executables without external functions? Usually, you'd just have to add `-lmylib` when you call `clang`, `gcc`, `ld` or however you're currently linking.

Comment: I am just generating the IR code using C++ `IR->print(llvm::errs())` then running it with `lli out.ll` - I am able to call functions like `extern sin` which exist in LLVM just, not the ones I define my self. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @pudility Ah, I see, In that case the simplest change would be to use `clang out.ll -lmylib -o myexecutable` to create an executable (if `mylib` is located in a non-standard directory, you'll also have to add the appropriate `-L` flag - basically you want the same flags as if you were compiling C code that uses the library).

Comment: that makes sense, but I am getting an error (see the updated question) when I try to run that.

Comment: @pudility Is your library actually called `mylib`? If not, you should change that part of the command accordingly. Also make sure that the library files name matches your system's naming conventions (e.g. `libmylib.so` on Unix-like systems) and that it's located in a directory that's part of your library search path (or you're using the appropriate `-L` flags). As I said, the flags should look exactly as they would if you were compiling  a C program that uses that library.

Comment: Sorry for all the question - I was able to link my cpp file to the llvm ir code with `clang out.ll -c lib -o out`, but I got an error when I tried to run it (edit 3)

Comment: @pudility `clang` produces native executables. So just run it without `lli`.

Comment: That does not really work for me `zsh: exec format error: ./out` thank you again for all the help.

Comment: @pudility I believe you've called your executable `a.out`, not `out`.

Comment: `a.out` was not generated

Comment: Sorry, I was finally able to figure it out! Thank you for all the help!